# Is this right way to set bits of enum?

Tags: c++, enums, bit, bitwise-operators

I have bitwise enum for save a two state settings of some class. I try to develope easy function to switch the bit ON or OFF.
Is this proper and quick way to do it?

```
enum myEnum { eeNull = 0, ee1 = 1, ee2 = 2, ee4 = 4, ee8 = 8 };

template<class T>
inline T &SetBit(T &eValue, const int iBit, const bool bState)
{
    return eValue = (T) ((eValue| (iBit * bState)) & ~(iBit * !bState));
}

int main()
{
    myEnum eE;

    eE = eeNull;

    SetBit<myEnum>(eE, ee2, true);
    SetBit<myEnum>(eE, ee1, true);
    SetBit<myEnum>(eE, ee2, false);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can omit `<myEnum>`.

Comment: Which version of C++ do you use? Can you use, for example, concepts (C++20)?

Comment: I need for back compatibilty C++ 17

Comment: side node, in C++ it is more common to use `enum class`

Comment: I know, it is more safe, but more difficult to use (you must use enum::eValue instead eValue) and completely explicit retyping. If you have system and use namespaces, you can to keep good order in enum without class.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works but using `std::bitset` makes it much cleaner.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
enum myEnum { ee1 = 0, ee2 = 1, ee4 = 2, ee8 = 3 };
int main()
{
    std::bitset<4> bE{0};
    bE[ee2] = true;
    bE[ee1] = true;
    bE[ee2] = false;
    std::cout << bE.to_string() << "\n";
}
```

I bet every new person looking at your code will have to take some time to figure out whether the function actually does what it is supposed to do and why it is written this way.

Edit: I rephrased my answer because of the commotion in the comments.

Comment: OP probably wants strong typing. With `bitset`, all 4-bit objects have the same type, which may lead to confusion.

Comment: I don't see a difference in that context (strong typing) between enum and bitset. Bitset just tells you that you are interested in the bits of the variable. Enum is actually intended to be a type of specific values, but is here used as a convenient way to define some values (`ee1 | ee2` isn't part of that enum type).

Comment: @stefaanv -- storing values in an `enum` that are different from the named enumerators is well defined, meaningful, and often useful. **One** way to use enumerated types is to hold a set of named values, but that is not the only use. `ee1 | ee2` is a valid value for `myEnum`.

Comment: @PeteBecker I know it is done and it is valid, but it is not what enums were meant to be.

Comment: @stefaanv -- it's **exactly** what enums were meant to be. Both the C and C++ standards go through the details of what values are valid given a set of enumerators; that wouldn't be necessary if they were intended to be limited to the values of the enumerators themselves. You might be thinking in Java...

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm thinking programming in general. C didn't invent enums.

Comment: @stefaanv -- there are lots of things that we learn about "programming in general" that don't apply to particular languages. This is just one of them. Enums in C and C++ have, deliberately, much broader usage than you suggest. If you're going to make a sweeping generalization about how a particular language construct is intended to be used, based not on actual usage in the language but, instead, on some notion of "programming in general" then you need to say so explicitly and not leave it to comments to clarify what you're talking about.

Comment: @anatolyg For strong typing, OP can put the bitset in a struct. I think this solution is better than re-implementing the bitset.

Comment: @AykhanHagverdili Using `enum` in this way is a consecrated idiom in C and C++. It's present in K&R (the first version) and in the Posix standard. Stricter type checking in C++ (and in modern C?) mean that you have to provide user defined operators for `|` and `&`, but that's no big deal. (I've got a program which will generate the operators automatically floating around somewhere.)

Comment: @PeteBecker [cpp-reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) starts with: "An enumeration is a distinct type whose value is restricted to a range of values" which is what I stated is the original meaning of enums. Also C++ introduced `enum class` which is closer how to enumerations actually work.

Comment: @stefaanv -- that "range of values" can, and usually does, contain more values than the specified enumerators. That's the way enumerations in C++ actually work; it doesn't matter that other languages define them differently, or that `enum class` is more like whatever you think an `enum` is. Incidentally, the "commotion in the comments" is because you refuse to accept that what you keep saying in the comments is simply wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it typically:

```
enum myEnum {
    ee1 = 1 << 0,
    ee2 = 1 << 1,
    ee3 = 1 << 2,
    ee4 = 1 << 3
};

int foo(int flag) {
    // Turn on ee1
    flag |= ee1;

    // Turn off ee3
    flag &= ~ee3;

    return flag;
}
```

Comment: But I want to universal function, for turn ON or turn OFF. Maybe will be quicker "if(true) flag |= ee1; else flag &= ~ee1; ?

Comment: @MichalHadraba sounds like you want to use a [bitset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

Comment: Make `TurnOn(T&, int n)` and `TurnOff(T&, int n)` functions, they would be better readable than `SetBit(..., true)` and `SetBit(..., false)`.

Comment: And more easy to use. It is good idea. But I use value from checkbox, so I dont know if I am turning on or off.

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution is to overload operators `|` and `&` (and `|=` and `&=`, of course), using the appropriate casts in the operators, something like:

```
//  Note that when working with bit masks,
//  it's usual to specify values in hex (or octal or binary).
enum MyEnum {
    eeNull = 0,
    ee1 = 0x01,
    ee2 = 0x02,
    ee4 = 0x04,
    ee8 = 0x08
};

MyEnum
operator|( MyEnum left, MyEnum right )
{
    return static_cast<MyEnum>( static_cast<unsigned>( left ) | static_cast<unsigned>( right ) );
}

MyEnum
operator&( MyEnum left, MyEnum right )
{
    return static_cast<MyEnum>( static_cast<unsigned>( left ) & static_cast<unsigned>( right ) );
}

MyEnum&
operator|=( MyEnum& left, MyEnum right )
{
    left = left | right;
    return left;
}

MyEnum&
operator&=( MyEnum& left, MyEnum right )
{
    left = left & right;
    return left;
}
```

This allows using the usual operators to set bits. An alternative is to use `+` to add a value to the set, and `-` to remove it. This is arguably abuse of operator overloading, since the operations aren't really related to addition and subtraction, but I've found it occasionally useful, and plebiscited by my colleagues.It allows writing: `flag -= ee2;`, rather than `flag &= ~ee2;` to turn a bit off.

Comment: If you're going to overload those operators, you might as well make it an enum class

Comment: @AykhanHagverdili What does that change? Without a user defined overload, `|` and `&` are still undefined operations. (I do think it a good idea to use scoped enums in most cases, but that wasn't the question here.)

Comment: Because there is no point in overloading these operators for the unscoped enums as they work by default.

Comment: @AykhanHagverdili The operators work, but the results are an `int`, and cannot be assigned to a variable with the enum type, nor be passed to a function expecting the enum type.

Comment: I see. Maybe that's a good thing though, do we want objects of type `MyEnum` that do not match any of the enum values? Maybe it would be good to have your operators return a 3rd type called `Flags<MyEnum>` or something like that.

Comment: MS Visual Studio actually supports bitmap-enums in its QuickWatch window. For example, if I have `myEnum x = (myEnum)5`, QuickWatch shows its value as `ee1 | ee4 (5)`. If they took special care in UI to support it, I think we as programmers shouldn't be afraid to use this feature.

Comment: @AykhanHagverdili We do. It's a standard idiom in C or C++, used from the very beginnings of C, and explicitly supported by the standard. As anatoyg points out, the Microsoft debugger even understands it, and displays the values appropriately. (I assume that this functionality is limited to cases where there are no ambiguities.)

Comment: @JamesKanze The standard idiom doesn't cast it back to the original enum type apparently, that's something you're adding here.

Comment: @AykhanHagverdili You can't use it to initialize the enum type without casting it back. In C, you don't cast it back, and you can't overload the operators, but at least when I was last using C, you could initialize an enum with an int -- you can't in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code is correct. It's usually implemented by bitwise `&` instead of multiplication, but I hope the compiler will understand multiplication by `bool` too, and produce good code.

Are you sure you need to return a reference to the value? This does no harm directly, but it allows writing complicated expressions with `SetBit`, which could be dangerous. If you return `void` instead, it will be harder to write code with side effects.

Bit-fiddling code usually uses unsigned types, because they have defined overflow behavior. Your code uses signed `int`, which is fine, but for highest bit position (31) may behave in surprising ways (undefined behavior).

Comment: The multiplication is used to set the given specific bits according to the state of the boolean (e.g. true: 0b1010, false: 0b0000), so either some bits set and no bits are reset or no bits are set and some are reset.

Comment: The compiler should convert multiplication to bitwise operations if they are more efficient (i.e. always). I have never checked if compilers really do this optimization (99% sure they do). This is purely a performance question; no doubt that the code is correct.

Comment: Thanks for detailed comment of my code.  I think, all is clear. But I think, it will not work the bitwise instead multiplication. I mean.  (iBit  & !bState) instead (iBit * !bState)...

Comment: Yes, the correct machine code is something like `ibit & (bstate - 1)`. The computer is supposed to generate it from your high-level code. We usually rely on the compiler for low-level stuff.